# Currency Code to locale JS

Tags: javascript, json, currency

Humour me here, but I have a trivial task of taking a number input, and format it to a currency code.

IE:

```
var value = 1000;
value.toLocaleString('en-AU, {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'AUD;,
    minimumFractionDigits: 2
});
// A$1,000.00
```

Which works - only problem is, this sits in a function, where I pass the value and the currency..

> function(value, currency)

Which now I have to maintain a list of currency to locale mappings. Is there a quick and lightweight way to format a number to currency. Im quite happy to sent a locale instead of the currency. Either way, I don't want to maintain two lists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where should I put the json result in money.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30531765/where-should-i-put-the-json-result-in-money-js)

Comment: @PaulSweatte not exactly... Im not concerned about currency conversion with relation to exchange rates..  It was more in relation to getting the local from a currency code, so `<input>AUD => <output>en-AU`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need two lists. Just have a map (object), using the currency as the key, and the locale as the value.

```js
var currencyToLocale = {
  'AUD': 'en-AU'
    // etc...
};

function formatAsCurrency(value, currency) {
  // get the locale from the map...
  var locale = currencyToLocale[currency];

  return value.toLocaleString(locale, {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: currency,
    minimumFractionDigits: 2
  });
};

console.log(formatAsCurrency(1000, 'AUD'));
```

Comment: This is what I currently have.... Problem with this solution is, I'm having to maintain an object.

Comment: What is there to maintain? You create it once, and it is done.

Answer (score 4):

If what you want is where to get the list of equivalences, I didn't found one, but you could build it matching these lists

currencies (find "ISO 4217 - Currency Code Maintenance: Get the Correct Currency Code"):
https://www.six-group.com/en/products-services/financial-information/data-standards.html

locales:
http://www.science.co.il/Language/Locale-codes.asp

Answer (score -2):

```
return new Intl.NumberFormat(locale, { style: 'currency', currency: currencyCode }).format(value)
```