# List/Array of available locale keys for currency in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular, pipe, locale, currency

I am preparing list(array) of available/supported locales for currency formatting but didn't found any useful content on that, my array is like below

```
const locale = [
  { code:"en_in", name:"English (India)" },
  { code:"en_mt", name:"English (Malta)" },
  { code:"en_nz", name:"English (New Zealand)" }
]
```

I am using code into `new Intl.NumberFormat()` method, Can anyone provide me list of locales that support `new Intl.NumberFormat()` method.

Thanks!

Comment: duplicates [Is it possible to list all known localized currencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59183982/is-it-possible-to-list-all-known-localized-currencies) and [Get List of Supported Currencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58029344/get-list-of-supported-currencies) and [Currency Code to locale JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35051169/currency-code-to-locale-js)

Comment: @pilchard Above link's doesn't contain any array that what I am actually asking.

Comment: SO is not a coding service. There are links to the relevant ISO sources in most of the duplicates, and a little Googling will turn up multiple libraries that fulfill your requirements.